# Visualizing iterated projective harmonic conjugates with the golden ratio

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to visualize the explanation below as the wiki article and the referenced paper don't have any illustrations.  The end of the paper references the golden angle appearing in the limit of successive iterations.  What I'm imagining is a clock where a bunch of points stacking up ('iterations') around one hand pointing at around 2 and the other around 10 (so 10:10 am/pm), forming 137 degrees between the hands, and infinity is at 12.  Am I on the right track?

"Let P0, P1, P2 be three different points on the real projective line. Consider the infinite sequence of points Pn, where Pn is the harmonic conjugate of Pn-3 with respect to Pn-1, Pn-2 for n > 2. This sequence is convergent." https://forumgeom.fau.edu/FG2016volume16/FG201655.pdf

Answer (score 1):

The Wikipedia article [Projective harmonic conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_harmonic_conjugate) states

> [...] four points form a harmonic tetrad when two harmonically
> separate the others. The condition
> $$ (c,d;a,b) = -1,\; \text{ equivalently }\; 2(cd+ab) = (c+d)(a+b), $$
> characterizes harmonic tetrads.

The end of the Wikipedia article has a section on iterated projective
harmonic conjugates and the golden ratio. This references the 2016 Forum
Geometricorum paper you mention. The paper assumes that the points form
a geometric sequence $q^n$. Using the harmonic tetrad condition with
$\, a = q^{n+1}, b = q^{n+2}, c = q^{n+0}, d = q^{n+3}\, $ requires that
$\, 0 = 1 + 3q + q^2. \,$ The two roots are $q_\pm = -(3\pm\sqrt{5})/2.$
Both roots are negative and are reciprocals of each other. The sequence
$\,q_\pm^n\,$ is alternating in sign. The sequence for $\,q_-\,$ converges
to $0$ and for $\,q_+\,$ diverges to infinity. This is for type $1$.

The type $3$ sequence assumes
$\, a = q^{n+0}, b = q^{n+1}, c = q^{n+2}, d = q^{n+3}\,$ which leads to
$\, 0 = 2 + 3q + 2q^2. \,$ The two roots are $q_\pm = (-3\pm\sqrt{-7})/4.$
The roots are conjugate complex numbers on the unit circle in the complex
plane. The paper states

> the points $\,q_+^n\,$ lie dense on the unit circle and correspondingly
> $(P_n)$ is dense on the projective real line.
>
> $\quad$ We remark that even though type 3 sequences seem not to be
> related to the golden ratio, the rotation angle $\,\arg(q_+)\approx
> 138.59^\circ\,$ is curiously very near to the golden angle $\,\frac{
> 360^\circ}{\Phi^2}\approx 137.5^\circ$.

In this type $3$ case, the points are dense in the circle although
the rotation angle between consecutive sequence points is very near
to the golden angle. Your image of

> a clock where a bunch of points stacking up ('iterations') around one hand pointing at around 2 and the other around 10 (so 10:10 am/pm), forming 137 degrees between the hands, and infinity is at 12.

is not an accurate picture. Your mention of "infinity is at 12" may
be referring to the model of the projective real line as a circle via
stereographic projection. This would apply only to type $1$ sequence.
For type $3$ sequence the model is the unit circle in the complex
plane which is very different.

Comment: Is it possible to visualize the Type 3 sequence, specifically where the 'rotation angle' of ≈138.59 would be seen on the complex unit circle? I'm imagining maybe a sunflower head... is it perhaps that type of pattern of seeds 137 degrees away from each other?  ...Though perhaps that can't be right because that would be a disc not the unit circle.  If there's just a unit circle getting a bunch of type 3 points scattered all around it to infinity then I don't see from where to where there's apparently this ≈138.59 degrees manifesting after iteration....

Comment: @Svenn Thanks for that comment! In my answer I wrote "the rotation angle between consecutive sequence points is very near to the golden angle." This is not visible if the points are all on the unit circle. It becomes visible if the root $q$ is increased in magnitude in which case the points $q^n$ would lie on a logarithmic spiral and the angle between consecutive points would become visible.

Comment: Thank you very much I think I'm getting a better idea of it now.  I'm terrible at even the basics of complex functions, but could one perhaps capture the image of that logarithmic spiral you mention as a loxodrome on the Riemann sphere, coiling out from the South Pole and reaching the equator/unit circle?  With the understanding that the spiral gets 'projected' onto the equatorial unit circle (and thus disappearing the angle between the points).  If I'm way off anyone can just let me know without unpacking why, I know it takes time to explain these :)